# Access numerical key in md-directive

Tags: angularjs

I've a Json object containing a numerical key and i would like to access it in a ng directive.

Look at that object :

```
{ 0 : { value : { firstname : "John" , lastname : "Doe" } }
```

I would like to access the first name of that object in a md directive like :

```
<th md-column md-order-by="0.value.firstname">
```

It look like that md-order-by directive can't take a numerical key as argument...

Should I redefine that key or there is another way to access it ?

Comment: Could try `md-order-by="0['value'].firstname"` but if that doesn't work probably need to modify structure

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
$scope.obj = { 0 : { value : { firstname : "John" , lastname : "Doe" } };
```

Use a bracket notation property accessor:

```
<th md-column md-order-by="obj[0].value.firstname">
```